# Convert ArrayList<Map<String, String>> to jsonArray

Tags: java, json, arraylist

i need to convert my `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` object to the JSONArray

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
//I tried this

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(dataList);  

// I am importing (java-json.jar) for converting ArrayList to JSONArray
// But i can't put this array in to JqGrid in my jsp page it's does not give me any output
```

Comment: show your jsp source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Google's [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for easy conversion of Java objects to Json and vice versa

Try below code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray jsonArray = gson.toJsonTree(dataList).getAsJsonArray();
```

EDIT : Convert jsonArray to string

```
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(jsonArray); //This will convert JsonArray to Java string
```

Comment: i will try you code
if know how to convert that data into Json String then please tell me.

Comment: Uttam Thanks for the giving me response.